# Identity component of SO(2,1)

Tags: lie-groups, rotations

I am working on Lie groups, and I have several difficulties to show that the identity component of SO(2,1) is the product of an euclidian rotation fixing a vector X and an hyperbolic rotation in a plane containing X.

In the proof I have, they say that if A belongs to the identity component of SO(2,1), X and AX are linearly independant, which I agree.

My problem is, they say AX and X span a plan in which the dot product (of signature (2,1) ) is hyperbolic, in the sense that X is a negative vector and (AX + (AX,X) ) is a positive vector.

But how can AX + (AX,X) be a vector? Isn't it a addition between a vector and a scalar, hence undefined? 
And if the proof I have contains a mistake, can someone give me another?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to show that, in case $AX \neq X$, the restriction of the Lorentzian metric of signature $(2,1)$ to the  2-dimensional subspace spanned by $X, AX$ is a metric of signature $(1,1)$.